# Laravel 8: Missing required parameter for [Route: students.update]

Tags: forms, methods, routes, controller, laravel-8

So I'm trying to understand laravel since I'm new to it so I'm creating a simple crud application...
I'm kinda stuck with the editing part.

I'm having this error:

> Missing required parameter for [Route: students.update] [URI: students/{student}] [Missing parameter: student]

I'm pretty sure I passed a parameter which is the id of the selected row. Pls, help.tnx

Here's my controller:

```
 public function edit(Students $students)
    {
        return view('students.edit', compact('students'));
    }

public function update(Request $request, Students $students)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'fname' => 'required',
            'lname' => 'required',
            'age' => 'required',
            'course' => 'required'
        ]);
        $students->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('students.index')->with('success','Student updated successfully');
    }
```

Here's the view where the Edit button is

```
@foreach($students as $student)
          <tr>
            *some codes*
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('students.edit', $student->id) }}" class="btn btn-success" id="editBtn">Edit</a>          
            </td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
```

And here is the view of the Edit

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('students.update', $students->id) }}">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')

        *some codes*

        <input type="submit" id="update" class="btn btn-success" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Try with `{{ route('students.edit', ['student' => $student]) }}`, or maybe just `{{ route('students.edit', $student) }}`. Sidenote, including the relevant routes from `web.php` would help here, so we can see how you defined your Route. Also, Model names are singular, should be `Student $student`, instead of `Students $students`

Comment: I tried that that and it's not working, so I just restarted everything and it worked. Also, this time I made the Model names singular. thank you btw.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are passing `$students->id` and expecting student object.
try to pass `$students` as object.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('students.update', $students) }}">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')

        *some codes*

        <input type="submit" id="update" class="btn btn-success" value="Update"></button>
</form>
```

Same thing for editing:

```
<a href="{{ route('students.edit', $student) }}" class="btn btn-success" id="editBtn">Edit</a>
```